# Ada. Getting "Depends on" when running in terminal

Tags: ada

Does anyone know why you get the "blank depends on blank" in the terminal? Blank being names of files of course.

```
lab5b.adb:1:59: "Sorted_Hero_List (spec)" depends on "Hero_Handling (body)"
```

Comment: Show us the actual logs! If it’s a compiler problem compiling with `-gnatl` helps (you get a line-numbered listing with error messages in-line). However, `depends on` sounds more like a binding or linking problem. Again, **show us the logs**, by copy/paste, don’t try to interpret them.

Comment: Looks like a circular dependency, but then the error message should contain more than one line...

Answer (score 1):

I’m guessing that the first line of `lab5b.adb` is something like

```
with Sorted_Hero_List;
```

and that `Sorted_Hero_List` is a generic instantiation of `Hero_Handling`, and that you’ve only provided the compiler with that spec (`hero_handling.ads`) and not the body (`hero_handling.adb`).

Or it could just be that `Sorted_Hero_List` "with"s `Hero_Handling`.